# How to define Sass mixins with variable arguments

Tags: css, sass, less

In lesscss I can write mixins like this, such that calling `.myMixin(@a)` with one argument uses the first mixin, and calling it with two arguments `.myMixin(@a, @b)` uses the second version of the mixin.

```
.myMixin(@paramOne) {
  // do something with the single-parameter version of mixin
}

.myMixin(@paramOne, @paramTwo) {
  // do something with the two-parameter version of mixin
}
```

**How can I do the same thing in sass?** Or is there an even better way to accomplish this in the sass world?

Comment: I'd love to throw in my opinion too :) but with this project `sass` is the technology of choice and I can't change that.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what problem you're trying to solve that requires 2 mixins with the same name and differing arguments.

Comment: This is useful for margin, padding and any of the css properties that let you define them with multiple arguments in normal css. For example, `margin: 5px` vs `margin: 5px 10px`.

Comment: you can pass a list in parameter and do this check inside your mixin to know if the parameter is a single value or a list: `@if type-of( $param1 ) == list`

Comment: @bejonbee Why call `foo(5px, 10px)` when you can call `foo(5px 10px)`?  It sounds like you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: @cimmanon Your 2nd example wont work for my needs. I can't just write the values to css — there will be calculations and filters run on each input to change the mixin's behavior. The code I provided is a simplified version of what I'm trying to solve. I'm just trying to understand how sass handles multiple parameters this since I'm used to the lesscss way.

Comment: @bejonbee That's why I'm asking you what problem you're actually trying to solve.  "I want to recreate horrible functionality I learned from LESS" is not a real problem.

Comment: @cimmanon My question is not about a specific problem, it's about a less/sass language feature. In [less we can define a specific mixin](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-mixins-with-multiple-parameters) in many different ways and less figures out which version to run based on the arguments provided and/or [the guards](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature) defined. It doesn't look like sass supports multiple mixins with the same name, so the question is how do I change the mixin behavior for different param counts or values?

Comment: That's just it, you're not trying to learn the Sass way to do things.  You're the guy who wants to know how to do loops in a language like Haskell (which doesn't have loops).  That doesn't mean the problem can't be solved, it just means it requires a different way of thinking.  If you aren't interested in learning, by all means, accept lefoy's answer (though I think it is a poor one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set your second parameter to be `false` as the default value, and do a `@if` statement inside your mixin.

```
@mixin myMixin( $param1, $param2:false ){
    @if $param2 == false{
        // Do something
    }
    @else{
        // Do something with both parameters
    }
}
```

---

Edit: this a custom function I made to transform px unit into em unit. You can pass a list or a single value as parameter. You can also set a base and a line-height. Maybe you can find few tricks inside this function.

You can use it like this: `emify(10px 16px, 16px)`.

This will output: `0.625em 1em`

```
/**
*
* Emify
*    Transform px unit into em
* defaults:
*    base: 16
* usage:
*    emify(unit)
*    emify(unit, base)
*    emify(unit, line-height, base)
* examples:
*    emify(16px) = 1em
*    emify(16px, 10px) = 1.600em
*    emify(16px, 10px, 10px) = 1.600em / 1em
*
**/    
@function emify( $target, $lineheight: null, $base: null ) {

    @if $base == null and $lineheight == null { $base: 16 }
    @if $base == null and $lineheight != null { $base: $lineheight }

    [...]

}
```

Comment: Thank you @lefoy, your `emify` function clarifies alot.

Comment: Or use the [variable arguments option](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_arguments): @mixin foo($args...)

Comment: I didn't know about the variable argument, thanks for sharing.